# Несколько лишних вызовов функций

Tags: javascript, функции, settimeout

Есть вот такой сладер в нем слайды скрываюися с помощью значений opacity. Есть setTimeout который обеспечивает автоматическую смену слайдов. Но если я счелкаю по кнопкам то скрипт будто запускает несколько setTimeout и они через промежуток сработывают выбивая ритм. Не смотря на то что clearTimeout тоже есть

```js
"use strict"

const dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dot'),
  slids = document.querySelectorAll('.slid'),
  dotbox = document.getElementById('dotBox'),
  durationTimeout = 10000,
  sliderBox = document.getElementById('sliderBox');

let autoChange,
  showSlid = 0;

for (let z = 1; z < 3; z++) {
  slids[z].style.opacity = "0";
}
slids[showSlid].style.opacity = "1";
dots[showSlid].style.background = "#40babd";

function sliderMechanism() {
  offTimeout();

  dots[showSlid].style.background = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)";
  slids[showSlid].style.opacity = "0";
  showSlid++;
  if (showSlid == slids.length) {
    showSlid = 0;
  }
  slids[showSlid].style.opacity = "1";
  dots[showSlid].style.background = "#40babd";

  onTimeout();
}

function dotPress(event) {
  let target = event.target.dataset.dotNumber; //
  if (target != undefined && showSlid != target) {
    offTimeout();
    dots[showSlid].style.background = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)";
    slids[showSlid].style.opacity = "0";
    showSlid = Number(target);
    slids[showSlid].style.opacity = "1";
    dots[showSlid].style.background = "#40babd";
    onTimeout();
  }
}

function offTimeout() {
  clearTimeout(autoChange);
}

function onTimeout() {
  autoChange = setTimeout(sliderMechanism, durationTimeout);
}

sliderBox.addEventListener('mouseover', offTimeout);
sliderBox.addEventListener('mouseout', onTimeout);

dotBox.addEventListener('click', dotPress);

autoChange = setTimeout(sliderMechanism, durationTimeout);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  max-width: calc(100vw - ((100vw - 100%)));
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  background: #2d3436;
  max-width: calc(100vw - ((100vw - 100%)));
}

.dotBox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 510px;
  width: 100%;
}

.dot {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  height: 11px;
  width: 11px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
}

.dot:hover {
  background-color: #40babd
}

.sliderBox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
}

.slid {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 560px;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-position: center center !important;
  position: absolute;
  transition: ease 0.6s;
}

.slid:nth-child(1) {
  background: blue;
}

.slid:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}

.slid:nth-child(3) {
  background: green;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.inHeader {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/stylesForNew.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="inHeader">
      <div class="logo">
        <h1><img src="assets/images/logo-icon.svg" alt=""><strong>APP</strong>KIT</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="sliderBox">
    <div class="dotBox" id="dotBox">
      <div class="dot" data-dot-number="0"></div>
      <div class="dot" data-dot-number="1"></div>
      <div class="dot" data-dot-number="2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slid">

      </div>
      <div class="slid"></div>
      <div class="slid"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="assets/js/jsForNew.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Сделайте воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Как это сделать ?

Comment: Есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1114390/edit), там можно добавить сниппет с js\html\css, который можно запустить прямо здесь.

Comment: Вот длительность timeout 10 секунд. Но если щелкать по точкам несколько раз то через некоторое время он сам начнёт перещелкиваться. Выглядит так что clearTimeout не чистит переменную autoChange не чистит timeout

Comment: @БулатМустафин Я уже ответил на Ваш вопрос. Это не `clearTimeout` не чистит переменную, а Вы не чистите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onTimeout() {
    offTimeout(); // !!!
    autoChange = setTimeout(sliderMechanism, durationTimeout);
}
```

Плюс - тогда можно убрать вызовы `offTimeout` из `sliderMechanism` и `dotPress`.

Comment: Я не понял как но это сработало. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @БулатМустафин В обработчике `'mouseout'` Вы запускали новый timeout, не останавливая текущий.

Answer (score 0):

костыль от нефронтэндера:

- по клику на кнопку также выставлять некий глобальный флаг: `window.sliderWasSwitchedManually = true`
- в начало setTimeout добавить условие `if(window.sliderWasSwitchedManually) {window.sliderWasSwitchedManually = false; return;}`